# how to change the volume of sphere by matrix reduction in C language

Tags: c

I made a sphere filled by the value "den" in 3x3 matrix in c language.

```
double ***pos;
int nx = 10;
int ny = 10;
int nz = 10;

double radius = 4;
double den = 3;
for (int x =0; x <nx; x ++){
  for (int y =0; y <ny; y ++){
    for (int z =0; x <nz; z ++){
      double dis = (dx - x) *(dx - x)+ (dy - y)*(dy - y) + (dz - z)*(dz - z);
      if(radius*radius > dis)
        pos[x][y][z] = den;
      else
        pos[x][y][z] = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

I want to reduce the volume of sphere without simple modification of "double radius".

Comment: You never allocated any memory for `pos`.

Comment: Can you spot the typo in `for (int z =0; x <nz; z ++)`? Also, are there any reasons not to declare `pos` as `double pos[10][10][10];`?

Comment: You can approximate a reduction of the sphere by a factor of f (for example, f = .25 for a reduction to 25% of its former size) by setting each `pos[x][y][z]` to `pos[lround(x/f)][lround(y/f)][lround(z/f)]` if those indices are inside the array and to `den` if any index is outside it. Any reduction from the previous matrix instead of from the original specification of the radius will necessarily suffer quantization artifacts.

Comment: Incidentally, the data structure apparently intended is a three-dimensional matrix, not a “3x3 matrix”.

Comment: Following the comments from Eric Postpischil, I apply the code to my system. The volume is reduced, but the position of sphere is also changed. how can i do keep the position of sphere with reduced volume?